# SQL Join to function that returns table from comma delimited parameter. If parameter is null Join to all

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, conditional-statements, csv

Given the following stored procedure in TSQL that can be passed in a string of comma delimited IDs that is given to a function that returns a table of IDs for joining to, is there an elegant way to do this so if the passed in parameter, `@BomAssemIDs`, is NULL such that instead of no records selected, ALL are selected.

As a join it's filtering, but if `@BomAssemIDs` is null I don't want to use it.  I was trying to avoid additional code or dynamic SQL, so right now my solution would be a big if statement, one using the table function join and the other not using it.  Seems I should be able to express this elegantly but I can't grasp it. Using SQLServer 2012

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[up_BomAssem_by_BomAssemIDs]
    @JobID  int ,
    @BomAssemIDs varchar(2000) 
AS
BEGIN     
    SELECT ba.* 
    FROM BomAssem ba 
    JOIN dbo.uf_SplitIntIDsToTable(@BomAssemIDs) sl ON ba.BomAssemID = sl.RecID
    where ba.JobID = @JobID    
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you are only using the `join` to filter by, I would move it to the `where` clause (where filtering belongs) and then add an `OR` to test `where @BomAssemIDs is null` and if so allow all records through e.g.

```
SELECT ba.* 
FROM BomAssem ba
WHERE ba.JobID = @JobID
AND (
  @BomAssemIDs IS NULL
  OR ba.BomAssemID IN (select RecId from dbo.uf_SplitIntIDsToTable(@BomAssemIDs))
);
```

I would be remiss if I didn't point out that you'd be much better off passing in a list using a [Table Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) instead of a comma separated string.

Comment: Doh! yes, I was wrapped up in the join the obvious escaped me. I think as I have few points I don't have the right to vote?  But this works.  Er...Or I click on the check icon....double Doh.

Comment: Education....it's like magic!  I will review the Table parameter as well...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` with a `left join`:

```
SELECT ba.* 
FROM BomAssem ba LEFT JOIN
     dbo.uf_SplitIntIDsToTable(@BomAssemIDs) sl
     ON ba.BomAssemID = sl.RecID OR @BomAssemIDs IS NULL
WHERE ba.JobID = @JobID;
```

Or just use `union all`:

```
SELECT ba.* 
FROM BomAssem ba JOIN
     dbo.uf_SplitIntIDsToTable(@BomAssemIDs) sl
     ON ba.BomAssemID = sl.RecID 
WHERE ba.JobID = @JobID
UNION ALL
SELECT ba.* 
FROM BomAssem ba
WHERE @BomAssemIDs IS NULL
```

Comment: When @BomAssemID is Null no records are returned, not what I was looking for.